# Is NotNull needed on Kotlin?

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, bean-validation

I have a class:

```
class User(

    var name: String

)
```

And a mapped post request:

```
@PostMapping("/user")
fun test(@Valid @RequestBody user: User) {
    //...
}
```

What if a client will send a JSON of a user with `name: null`? Will it be rejected by the MVC Validator or an exception will be throwed? Should I annotate `name` with `@NotNull`? Unfortunately, I cannot check that because only can write tests (it is not available to create `User(null)`).

Comment: Are you asking about kotlin in general, or specifically how to handle this situation in Spring MVC (i.e. "as `@NotNull` is redundant when using Kotlin, how do I validate requests in which a non-null property isn't supplied in the request JSON?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tested, `@NotNull` doesn't affect on the MVC validation at all. You will only receive a `WARN` message in console which is normal:

> Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Instantiation of...

Answer (score 11):

You can avoid using `@NotNull`, as it'll never get triggered for non-nullable property (bean validation only kicks in after Jackson deserializes the JSON - which is where this will fail).

Assuming you're using [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin), then you should get an exception with [`MissingKotlinParameterException`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/Exceptions.kt) as the root cause, which you can then handle in a `@ControllerAdvice`. In your advice you can handle normal bean validation exceptions (e.g. `ConstraintViolationException`caused by `@Size`) and missing non-null constructor params (`MissingKotlinParameterException`) and return an API response indicating the fields in error.

The only caveat with this is that the `jackson-kotlin-module` [fails on the first missing property](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/58), unlike bean validation in Java, which will return all violations.

Answer (score 5):

Since `name` is a not-null parameter of `User`, it cannot accept `null`s, ever.

To guarantee that Kotlin compiler:

- inserts a `null` check inside the `User` constructor which throws an exception if some Java code tries to pass a `null`.
- annotates `name` with`@NotNull` in order to stay consistent with Java APIs
- <s>does not add any `@NotNull` annotation since there isn't one which everybody agrees on :(</s>

Here are the corresponding [docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#null-safety)

### Update

I have rechecked it, and Kotlin compiler v1.0.6 *does* insert `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` from `org.jetbrains.annotations`. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

My workarround for now (place the file anywhere):

```kotlin
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MissingKotlinParameterException::class)
    fun missingKotlinParameterException(ex: MissingKotlinParameterException): Error? {
        return createMissingKotlinParameterViolation(ex)
    }

    private fun createMissingKotlinParameterViolation(ex: MissingKotlinParameterException): Error{
        val error = Error(BAD_REQUEST.value(), "validation error")
        val errorFieldRegex = Regex("\\.([^.]*)\\[\\\"(.*)\"\\]\$")
        val errorMatch = errorFieldRegex.find(ex.path[0].description)!!
        val (objectName, field) = errorMatch.destructured
        error.addFieldError(objectName.decapitalize(), field, "must not be null")
        return error
    }

    data class Error(val status: Int, val message: String, val fieldErrors: MutableList<CustomFieldError> = mutableListOf()) {
        fun addFieldError(objectName: String, field: String, message: String) {
            val error = CustomFieldError(objectName, field, message)
            fieldErrors.add(error)
        }
    }

    data class CustomFieldError(val objectName: String, val field: String, val message: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following exception handler:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandlerResolver {

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  @ExceptionHandler(MissingKotlinParameterException::class)
  fun missingKotlinParameterException(ex: MissingKotlinParameterException): MyCustomError? {
    return MyCustomError(
      timestamp = LocalDateTime.now(),
      status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      exception = ex,
      validationMessages = listOf(
        ValidationMessage(
          field = ex.path.fold("") { result, segment ->
            if (segment.fieldName != null && result.isEmpty()) segment.fieldName
            else if (segment.fieldName != null) "$result.${segment.fieldName}"
            else "$result[${segment.index}]"
          },
          message = "value is required"
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

It supports exception for any Json path, for example: `arrayField[1].arrayItemField.childField`

MyCustomError and ValidationMessage classes:

```
data class MyCustomError(
  val timestamp: LocalDateTime,
  @JsonIgnore val status: HttpStatus,
  @JsonIgnore val exception: Exception? = null,
  val validationMessages: List<ValidationMessage>? = null
) {
  @JsonProperty("status") val statusCode = status.value()
  @JsonProperty("error") val statusReasonPhrase = status.reasonPhrase
  @JsonProperty("exception") val exceptionClass = exception?.javaClass?.name
  @JsonProperty("message") val exceptionMessage = exception?.message
}

data class ValidationMessage(val field: String, val message: String)
```